# Why is my BeautifulSoup code only scraping some Airbnb URLs?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape Airbnb data from airbnb.com using Beautiful Soup. However with the below code, not all the URLs are scraped even though the inspect HTML code has the class names correctly.

```
   ab_lists[:4]
   output of ab_list: ['www.airbnb.com/rooms/34594075?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000',
  'www.airbnb.com/rooms/34056273?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000',
  'www.airbnb.com/rooms/48028470?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000',
  'www.airbnb.com/rooms/46915499?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000']
```

In the above code, I have four urls for 4 airbnbs and I am trying to get the title of the airbnbs. I run the for loop for the above list to get further data:

```
 def get_pages(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    return soup

 for ab_url in ab_lists[:4]:
    ab_soup = get_pages("https://" + ab_url)
    a = ab_soup.select('div._mbmcsn')
    b = ab_soup.select('span._142pbzop')
    print(b)

 Output: [<span class="_142pbzop">(36 reviews)</span>]
 []
 []
 []
```

however, when I run the for loop, only some URLs are scraped, not all of them.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: probably there is some javascript that is loading Html elements, so you are not able to get those elements with a simple request. i would recommend checking selenium, you can use that to replicate browser

Comment: Can you post the links in text form?

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: @Tuqay So is there a workaround to do using beautiful soup before I can try selenium?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have updated my question

Comment: FYI it’s __scraped__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraping__) not scrapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you wish to grab from those pages are dynamic. `requests` module has nothing to do with dynamic content unless you use any api or any alternative link responsible for loading the same. However, I've used [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) to scrape the fields of your interest from those pages.

```
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
from pyppeteer import launch

links = [
    'www.airbnb.com/rooms/34594075?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000',
    'www.airbnb.com/rooms/34056273?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000',
    'www.airbnb.com/rooms/48028470?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000',
    'www.airbnb.com/rooms/46915499?adults=2&previous_page_section_name=1000'
]


async def fetch(page,url):
    await page.goto(url,{"waitUntil": "networkidle0"})
    name = await page.querySelectorEval('h1','(e => e.innerText)')
    review = await page.querySelectorEval('a[aria-label*="reviews"] > span','(e => e.innerText)')
    print(name,review)
        
async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False,autoClose=False)
    [page] = await browser.pages()
    for link in links:
        qualified_link = f"https://{link}"
        await fetch(page,qualified_link)
    await browser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
OGS - Studio 4 (36 reviews)
Bohemian London Living - Large Double Room! (20 reviews)
Bijoux yet luxurious -Belgravia, London 2 reviews
MODERN Double room NOX HOTELS Paddington (78 reviews)
```

Comment: Oh okay...got it..I will follow this method and extract other values..thank you very much for your help!